# Problem when attempting to put Ubuntu One in panel (12.04)

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-one, panel

I wanted to put the Ubuntu One icon in the panel so I could see the progress of my sync but when I try this is what I get....

```
mohd-arafat-hossain@TUD:~$ sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-indicator
[sudo] password for mohd-arafat-hossain: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntuone-indicator : Depends: indicator-ubuntuone but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have done these following steps before I did the above >>

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rye/ubuntuone-extras
sudo apt-get update
```

I have scanned for broken packages in Synaptic Package Manager but it shows that I have none.

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: yup and it didn't help :(

Comment: The package was renamed to `indicator-ubuntuone` so try `sudo apt-get install indicator-ubuntuone`

Comment: Want to make that an answer cause that solved my problem :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ubuntuone-indicator` package was renamed to `indicator-ubuntuone`

[image]

So installation command should be:

`sudo apt-get install indicator-ubuntuone`

Launchpad page of this PPA: [Unofficial Ubuntu One packages](https://launchpad.net/~rye/+archive/ubuntuone-extras)